# Enabling IIS 6 Scripting Tools via batch file

Tags: batch-file, iis

So I want to enable the features IIS 6 Management Console, IIS 6 scripting tools and IIS 6 Metabase and IIS 6 configurations compatibility via command lines or more specifically through a batch file.

I have used the following line to enable other features and has successfully worked by changing the feature name:

```
DISM /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-WebServerManagementTools
```

But for some reason the one's listed are not apart of the list of features recognized by the command prompt.

```
 DISM /online /get-features /format:table
```

So if anyone has a solution to this please share.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Years ago I did that with Package Manager like this:

```
start /w pkgmgr /iu:IIS-WebServerRole;IIS-ApplicationDevelopment;IIS-ASPNET;IIS-NetFxExtensibility;IIS-ISAPIExtensions;IIS-ISAPIFilter;IIS-Security;IIS-BasicAuthentication;IIS-RequestFiltering;IIS-ManagementConsole;IIS-ManagementService;IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility;IIS-Metabase;IIS-LegacySnapIn
```

You might try some of those features.

Comment: It worked for all of them except IIS 6 scripting tool

Comment: Try adding IIS-ManagementScriptingTools

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an older post, but this worked for me:

```
dism /online /Enable-Feature /All /FeatureName:IIS-LegacyScripts
```

After running that IIS 6 Scripting Tools was enabled